# How To Echo created at in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.6

This is my code :

```
@foreach($mcr as $value)
   <tr style="font-size: 12px" tabindex="0">
      <td>{{ $value->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

I try this but i get error **Data Missing**
I hope every one can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing your code `$someThing->created_at->format('Y-m-d')` is OK. so I think problem is in your data. Are you sure you already have feild `created_at` in each `$mcr` ?